# Why is my UIActivityIndicatorView is not centered on screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
```

Presently it appears in the bottom half.

Comment: Do you add it directly to `self.view` or to a subview thereof?

Comment: [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];

Comment: Based on some of your comments it sounds like your view is taller than you think it is. This can happen when you're designing in IB for the iphone 5 screen, but running on a device with a smaller screen.

Answer (score 15):

This will put the indicator in the center of your view (not the screen!):

```
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin)
```

The autoresizing keeps in in the center when its size changes (e.g. when switching screen orientation).

If it doesn't work, your problem is somewhere else. Try to log the size of your view, maybe it is not positioned correctly?

```
NSLog(@"View frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0f - activityIndicator.frame.size.width /2.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f - activityIndicator.frame.size.height /2.0f, activityIndicator.frame.size.width, activityIndicator.frame.size.height);
//then add to the view
```

Comment: its appearing at the same spot. About 3/4 down the screen

Answer (score 2):

why not just this way

```
activityIndicator.center =  self.view.center;

activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin)
```

this is working well without having to do those calculations as mentioned by others

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding indicator to parentView following logic should center the indicator on parent - It works for me.

```
 // ...
 CGSize parentSize = parentView.frame.size;
 UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
 activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(parentSize.width/2, parentSize.height/2);
 // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Set center in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

`- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    self.myActivityIndicator.center = self.view.center; 
}`

Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

i also have this problem, try this

```
activityIndicator.center =CGPointMake(480/2.0, 320/2.0);
```

Comment: That will only work if the view is 480x320 all the time. What about happens if the app is running on the iPhone 5 or is in a different orientation?

Comment: It will work only for static screen size. ex.iPhone 3.5'